# Html Form does not submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, networking, httprequest

In some rare cases, some of our users experience that the form submission does not work.

We checked that and saw that sometimes, i.e. when there is a slow connection, the "form.submit()" simply does not work. Resubmitting after a few seconds won't work either.

Info:

1. document.readyState is complete
2. No exception is thrown.

Has anyone experienced the same problem? How can we check if the form object and its methods and properties were properly loaded?

Comment: Hi. How is your form submitted ? Are you using a <button type="submit"> or do you bind an event to a button manually ?

Comment: In the described case I used an input-type "button" that called "form.submit()" from JS. However, I have also tried it with the input-type "submit" with no success.

Comment: Could you show us your code? The better would be a minimal code sample that behaves the same way as your code.